# How to extract specific text from a log file using linux terminal?

Tags: linux, awk, grep

I have a log file which contain lots of line like below:

```
2017-07-16 01:06:07 | 8801624874139 | http://192.168.5.1:2020/credit/purchase/4 | XpressLoan | {"resultCode":0,"resultMessage":"OK","amount":100000,"serviceFee":24400,"totalOutstandingdebt":124400,"msisdn":8801624874139}  
2017-07-16 01:06:24 | 8801628666938 | http://192.168.5.1:2020/credit/purchase/5 | XpressLoan | {"resultCode":0,"resultMessage":"OK","amount":50000,"serviceFee":12180,"totalOutstandingdebt":62180,"msisdn":8801628666938}
```

From the above log how can I get the amount value?

Expected output:

```
100000
50000
```

Comment: Pipe this to sed -n 's/".*amount":\\(.*\\),".*/\1/p'

Comment: That looks suspiciously like json in that field; consider a json parser.

Comment: @eins6180 On my machine this doesn't work. However I have a similar approach. In your approach you refer to a regex group that matches everything instead of numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$ awk -F\" '/amount/ {print $9}' file | sed 's/[:|,]//g'
100000
50000
```

OR:

```
$ sed 's/^.*amount\":\([0-9]*\),\".*$/\1/' file
100000
50000
```

**EDIT**

You can summarize the output of the first command if you pipe it again to awk like this example:

```
$ awk -F\" '/amount/ {print $9}' file | sed 's/[:|,]//g' |\
awk '{sum += $1} END {print sum}'
150000
```

Comment: (1) The first approach is very sensitive to possible future changes in the file format.  If some record is missing “resultCode” or “resultMessage”, or has some other field before “amount”, it will break.  (2) The second approach is somewhat sensitive to possible future changes in the file format.  If “amount” is ever the last field (so the amount value is followed by `}` instead of `,`), it will break.  But I’m nit-picking — if the file could vary that much, it would be the OP’s responsibility to tell us.  (3) You don’t need to escape the quotes.  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  (4) If the “amount” value is ever anything other than a sequence of digits — such as “100tons”, “−100”, or even “50.0” — your second answer will fail.  It’s probably safer to say `\([^,]*\)`.  (5) On any lines that don’t satisfy your substitution command (including those mentioned in paragraph #4), your second command will output the entire line.  The question doesn’t specify what to do in such a case; it might be better to say `sed -n` and then put a `p` at the end of the `s` command: `sed -n 's/…/…/p'`.

Comment: @Scott To both comments: I wasn't aware that JSon output is so volatile.

Comment: @JohnGoofy Can I get the summation from those returned values in a single command? I used your first command.

Comment: @Rezuan Yes, please review my edit.

Answer (score 4):

Use combination of ***awk*** + [***jq***](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/) (JSON manipulation tool):

```
awk '{ print $10 }' logfile | jq -r '.amount'
```

The output:

```
100000
50000
```

---

With such kind of approach you'll be able to extract any/multiple keys/values from your JSON-encoded field

Comment: That's pretty neat, I wasn't aware of `jq`, cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Could use multiple `awk` to get the needed data.

```
awk -F"|" {'print $5'}| awk -F"," '{print $3}'| awk -F":" '{print $2}'
```

- the first awk will get you to the `{}` data
- the second awk will give you the `key:value`
- the third awk will give you the value of the key

even if format will change then the patter should be identified by the separators and adjust it accordingly.

e.g.:

```
my_var="2017-07-16 01:06:07 | 8801624874139 | http://192.168.5.1:2020/credit/purchase/4 | XpressLoan | {"resultCode":0,"resultMessage":"OK","amount":100000,"serviceFee":24400,"totalOutstandingdebt":124400,"msisdn":8801624874139}"

$ echo $my_var | awk -F"|" {'print $5'}
 {resultCode:0,resultMessage:OK,amount:100000,serviceFee:24400,totalOutstandingdebt:124400,msisdn:8801624874139}

$ echo $my_var | awk -F"|" {'print $5'}| awk -F"," '{print $4}'
serviceFee:24400

$ echo $my_var | awk -F"|" {'print $5'}| awk -F"," '{print $3}'| awk -F":" '{print $2}'
100000
```